# Conditional Null Operator invalid type in given context

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

Working with a Legacy Application, ASP.Net, c#.
Trying to append my log4net messages with the SessionWrapper.UserDisplayName

The hiccup is if the sessionwrapper is not defined, i don't want it to bomb, i just want it to treat it as null or empty and I'm trying to avoid writing a multiple lines of code.

Using this as the base for my idea:

```
    banana = null;
    string result2 = banana?.prop1 + "something new";
```

result 2 = something new

Applying that concept to my code:

```
SessionWrapper?.UserDisplayName + "error message"
```

I get an error compiling saying:
"SessionWrapper is a type and invalid int the current context"

Any insight  is greatly appreciated -

Comment: SessionWrapper is a class or an instance? are you trying to access the static field "UserDisplayName"?

Answer (score 1):

A type is not a value and is therefore never `null`. If `UserDisplayName` is a static property of this type, then it might be null; however, it is okay to concatenate `null` with a string. `null` will be treated like an empty string.

Simply write

```
string result = SessionWrapper.UserDisplayName + "error message";
```

In `banana?.prop1` the null-condition-operator is only useful if `banana` is `null`. The expression is equivalent to `banana == null ? (string)null : banana.prop1`.

If you want to treat the case where `prop1` could be null, then use the null-coalescing operator `??`.

```
string result2 = (banana.prop1 ?? "<empty>") + "something new";
```

Of course you can combine the two.

```
string result2 = (banana?.prop1 ?? "<empty>") + "something new";
```

Now, both, `banana` and `prop1` can be null. In both cases you will get the result `"<empty>something new"`.